# TypeError: Expected int64, but got 0.0 of type 'float'

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

this is the code

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),batch_size=32,epochs=10,verbose=1,callbacks=Early_Stoping)
```

and this is the error

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed eval> in <module>

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

TypeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 142, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 268, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2146, in binary_crossentropy
        label_smoothing = tf.convert_to_tensor(label_smoothing, dtype=y_pred.dtype)

    TypeError: Expected int64, but got 0.0 of type 'float'.
help me to resolve this error
```

Comment: try `label_smoothing = tf.convert_to_tensor(label_smoothing, dtype=int64)`